# I do not understand why I get No module named 'pandas_datareader' when I installed it through Anaconda navigator and can see it installed?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda

I am trying to use this module pandas-datareader through VS Code, but whenever I try to run:

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
```

I get this message back:`No module named 'pandas_datareader'`

However i did. install it through anaconda navigator. and can see it as installed. 
When i check by opening the terminal and try reintalling it:

```
conda install pandas-datareader
```

I get the message:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done
# All requested packages already installed.
```

What am I doing wrong or not understanding? 
Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Can you share the contents of the environment? The issue usually is that you added the package to a certain Python installation, and are executing the program with a different Python installation. Have you followed the instructions at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments ?

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I didn't I had to choose an environment, its my first time dealing with such. But yes i just did and. selected conda and now it works !

Comment: Be sure to create a new environment for each project! Good luck :)